# Salvar dados de arquivo em um map c++

Tags: c++, arquivo, estrutura-de-dados, map

Não estou conseguindo ler corretamente um arquivo txt e transferir para um map em c++.

O codigo que eu desenvolvi ele funciona so se não tiver espaços " " no txt, se tiver entra em loop e não funciona. Eis o codigo:

```
void dados::pesquisarProdutos(){

arq.open("produtos.txt",ios::in);

if (arq.fail()){
    perror("erro ao pesquisar: ");
    sleep(1);
    return;
}

string nome;
float preco;
int qnt;

while (!arq.eof()){
    arq >> nome >> preco >> qnt;
    map1.insert(make_pair(nome,loja(nome,preco,qnt)));
}

cout << "Qual produto procura: ";
getline(cin,nome);

it = map1.find(nome);

cout << it->first << "preco: "<< it->second.getPreco() << "quantidade: "<<
     it->second.getEstoque();

arq.close();}
```

Se o nome do produto for, por exemplo, arroz, ele salva no map e funciona normal, agora se for arroz branco, da erro. Pelo jeito o problema é na leitura do espaço, mas não sei como resolver.

Já agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: Por que a tag C?  C e C++ são programa totalmente distintos.

Answer (score 1):

Um *stream* normalmente é extraída por espaços em brancos. Assim, os campos de uma *stream* são separados por este delimitador e quando um dos campos possui este delimitador internamente, dá conflito, conforme vc percebeu.

A solução mais simples é vc modificar este delimitador, substituindo-o, por exemplo por '|'. Então, a primeira coisa que vc deve fazer é alterar como os campos estão formatados em seu arquivo txt, tendo cada linha como algo do tipo:

```
nome | preço | quantidade
```

Após isso, basta apenas fazer a separação da linha neste novo formato. Para isso, vc deve converter esta linha em um novo *stream*, o [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), usando este novo delimitador e extrair os dados conforme tinha feito antes.

Por exemplo:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    // Simulando um stream do arquivo
    std::stringstream str("foo bar | 5.44 | 5\nbaar fooo | 6.01 |10");
    std::string name;
    double price;
    int qnt;

    std::string tmp; // serve para inicializar o stringstream stream
    while (std::getline(str, tmp))
    {
        std::stringstream stream(tmp);
        std::getline(stream, name, '|'); // extraindo name

        std::getline(stream, tmp, '|');  // extraindo price e convertendo
        price = std::atof(tmp.c_str());

        std::getline(stream, tmp, '|');  // extraindo qnt e convertendo
        qnt = std::atoi(tmp.c_str());

        std::cout << name << " | " << price << " | " << qnt << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, usar um espaço em branco como delimitador de campos não é uma boa ideia.

Sugiro que seus dados utilizem outro tipo de delimitador, como por exemplo, o ponto-e-vírgula (`;`):

```
Arroz Integral;10.50;100
Arroz Branco;15.50;100
Feijao Preto;5.70;350
Feijao Carioca;4.50;200
Milho;3.25;50
Trigo;7.10;50
```

Dessa forma, você pode utilizar um código como esse para solucionar o seu problema:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>


class Produto
{
    public:

        Produto( void ) {}
        virtual ~Produto( void ) {}

        std::string nome( void ){ return m_nome; }
        float preco( void ){ return m_preco; }
        int qnt( void ){ return m_qnt; }

        void parse( std::string s )
        {
            std::size_t pos = 0;
            std::string tok;
            std::vector< std::string > v;

            while((pos = s.find(";")) != std::string::npos)
            {
                tok = s.substr( 0, pos );
                v.push_back(tok);
                s.erase( 0, pos + 1 );
            }

            v.push_back(s);

            m_nome = v[0];
            m_preco = atof(v[1].c_str());
            m_qnt = atoi(v[2].c_str());
        }

    private:

        std::string m_nome;
        float m_preco;
        int m_qnt;
};


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    std::ifstream arq( "produtos.txt" );
    std::string linha;
    std::map< std::string, Produto > mp;
    std::map< std::string, Produto >::iterator it;

    while( std::getline( arq, linha ) )
    {
        Produto p;
        p.parse( linha );
        mp.insert( std::make_pair( p.nome(), p ) );
    }

    it = mp.find(argv[1]);

    if( it == mp.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "Produto Nao Encontrado!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Produto & p = it->second;

    std::cout << "Nome: " << p.nome() << std::endl
              << "Preco: " << p.preco() << std::endl
              << "Quantidade: " << p.qnt() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
$ ./produtos "Banana"
Produto Nao Encontrado!

$ ./produtos "Milho"
Nome: Milho
Preco: 3.25
Quantidade: 50

$ ./produtos "Arroz Integral"
Nome: Arroz Integral
Preco: 10.5
Quantidade: 100

$ ./produtos "Feijao Carioca"
Nome: Feijao Carioca
Preco: 4.5
Quantidade: 200
```